# How to hide execl() arguments from ps?

Tags: c, fork, exec, ps, unistd.h

**How to hide/change a process argument after `execl()`? or how can we hide/change arguments of a child process that is using `system()` / `execl()`?**

Working on [SHC](https://github.com/neurobin/shc) (the purpose of this application is to compile a bash script into a binary) i am using `execl()` function to execute the sh script; The problem is that `execl()` argument are exposed to `ps`; the purpose of this question is to make SHC just a little bit more reliable and solve some issues reported by users.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

    int runThis;

    //Create child process
    if(fork() == 0){ 
        printf("I'm the child\n");
        //runThis = system("echo test; sleep 30");
        runThis = execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "echo test; sleep 30", (char *) 0);
        exit(0);
    } else {
        printf("I'm the parent.\n");
    }

    printf("Continue main\n");

    return 0;
}
```

When running this code, `sh -c echo test; sleep 30` is exposed to `ps`

**Solution attempt 1: successful but not reliable**

Hiding commands arguments with `ld_preload` can be done with this [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403918) or by using `setenv("LD_PRELOAD","myLib.so",1);` (`dlopen()` will not work with `execl()`), this solution require indeed loading a library to our application.

**Solution attempt 2: semi successful**

Wrapping `__libc_start_main` with `ld --wrap=symbol`, this works for parent but the code is not wrapped after `execl()` / `system()`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int __real___libc_start_main(int (*main) (int, char **, char **), int argc, char **ubp_av, void (*init) (void), void (*fini)(void), void (*rtld_fini)(void), void (*stack_end));

int __wrap___libc_start_main(int (*main) (int, char **, char **), int argc, char **ubp_av, void (*init) (void), void (*fini)(void), void (*rtld_fini)(void), void (*stack_end)) {    
    printf("Main called\n");
    //ubp_av[1] = "test";
    int result = __real___libc_start_main(main, argc, ubp_av, init, fini, rtld_fini, stack_end);
    return result;
}
```

Build commands: (`wrap.c` is the code above and `example.c` is the first code sample)

```
gcc -c example.c -o 1.o;
gcc -c wrap.c -o 2.o;  
gcc -Wl,-wrap,__libc_start_main -Wl,-wrap=__libc_start_main 1.o 2.o -o myapp
```

**Solution attempt 3: semi successful**

Similar to attempt 2, it consist of linking the code of attempt 1 at build time... but this does not work with `execl()`

- build the library as libfoo or an other name `gcc -Wall -O2 -fpic -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so -ldl -o libfoo.so wrap.c` (wrap.c is the code from attempt 1)
- install it `sudo ln -s /path/libfoo.so /usr/lib64/libfoo.so`
- link it `gcc example.c -o myapp -L.. -lfoo`

**Solution attempt 4: related but not useful here**

Ptrace can be used from the parent process to modify the child argument after `execl()` [example-1](https://github.com/alfonsosanchezbeato/ptrace-redirect) [example-2](https://github.com/emptymonkey/ptrace_do)

Comment: Why are you trying to hide them? There is no race-free way to do this, but it sounds like an XY problem...

Comment: shc is not intended to hide the bash content completely (not possible) but at least make it difficult to uncover the converted script, it's why i want to hide it from ps

Comment: That's not possible. Ever used `strace`? Also, what you're asking for is really bordering on malware, so you should probably clarify what you're doing if it's not malicious. Asking for help developing malware is generally off-topic.

Comment: Yes used strace before i am having some reading about how to use it as ld_preload alternative (i did use it to implement -H -s feature to shc), this is not for a malicious purpose i want to solve https://github.com/neurobin/shc/issues/7 and https://github.com/neurobin/shc/issues/65 and https://github.com/neurobin/shc/issues/69

Comment: I don't know what you mean by using `strace` as an "`LD_PRELOAD` alternative". My point was that the user can always observe what arguments `execve` is called with simply by using `strace` (among other ways).

Comment: Yes i know, the parent process is already using ptrace (in the original application not the example), strace wont work because we could only have a single tracer per process. When i talked about strace as alternative to LD_PRELOAD i was thinking of using ptrace to modify the child system call and thus remove/replace the argument from the tracer. currently i am trying to convert the LD_PRELOAD library code to be used with "ld --wrap=symbol"... all of this is a little complicated for me as i work on c project just from time to time

Comment: I updated the question with further solution attempt (semi successful). The code have many ways of reversing/retrieving the arguments, even with the wished solution here there will be a window at startup where the argument would be exposed. i just want the code to have a minimal protection and make it a little hard to reverse.

Comment: So, you want to distribute something that runs on someone else's computer, completely under their control, and you want to hide what it does from them?  That is not going to work.

Comment: The purpose of SHC (https://github.com/neurobin/shc) is to compile a bash script into a binary and thus make it hard to reverse like any binary

Comment: Irrelevant. Because it's not hard. It's still running on someone else's computer, under their complete control.  And **there is no way to obfuscate what your code actually does**, because it **does it**. Read/write a file? Obvious, with no way to obfuscate. In this case, as @R.. already posted, there are numerous ways to get command line arguments.  Defeating your LD_PRELOAD hack is trivial, while [also being completely unnecessary to defeat in the first place](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84847/is-there-an-easy-way-to-log-all-commands-executed-including-command-line-argume).

Comment: You are right, any binary can be watched to discover what it does and i know there is no way to bypass that, the purpose here is to make SHC just a little bit more reliable and solve some issues reported by users.

Comment: What shc is claiming to do is fundamentally nonsense, and fundamentally malicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternative solution:**

Bash content can be piped and thus hidden from ps

```
script="script goes here"
echo $script | bash
```

**Mitigated solution:**

This is not a perfect solution, but it will answer the question, this code will create an `shc_x.c` under /tmp build it, then preload it with environment variable.

shc_x.c, inject the bash sh content to ******** argument by replacing it and change the location of child commands arguments and thus hide them from ps as well.

**shc_x.c:** (this file is generated with the second code)

```
/*
 * Copyright 2019 - Intika <intika@librefox.org>
 * Replace ******** with secret read from fd 21
 * Also change arguments location of sub commands (sh script commands)
 * gcc -Wall -fpic -shared -o shc_secret.so shc_secret.c -ldl 
 */

#define _GNU_SOURCE /* needed to get RTLD_NEXT defined in dlfcn.h */
#define PLACEHOLDER "********"
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

static char secret[128000]; //max size
typedef int (*pfi)(int, char **, char **);
static pfi real_main;

// copy argv to new location
char **copyargs(int argc, char** argv){
    char **newargv = malloc((argc+1)*sizeof(*argv));
    char *from,*to;
    int i,len;

    for(i = 0; i<argc; i++){
        from = argv[i];
        len = strlen(from)+1;
        to = malloc(len);
        memcpy(to,from,len);
        // zap old argv space
        memset(from,'\0',len);      
        newargv[i] = to;
        argv[i] = 0;
    }
    newargv[argc] = 0;
    return newargv;
}

static int mymain(int argc, char** argv, char** env) {
    //fprintf(stderr, "Inject main argc = %d\n", argc);
    return real_main(argc, copyargs(argc,argv), env);
}

int __libc_start_main(int (*main) (int, char**, char**),
                      int argc,
                      char **argv,
                      void (*init) (void),
                      void (*fini)(void),
                      void (*rtld_fini)(void),
                      void (*stack_end)){
    static int (*real___libc_start_main)() = NULL;
    int n;

    if (!real___libc_start_main) {
        real___libc_start_main = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "__libc_start_main");
        if (!real___libc_start_main) abort();
    }

    n = read(21, secret, sizeof(secret));
    if (n > 0) {
      int i;

    if (secret[n - 1] == '\n') secret[--n] = '\0'; 
      for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        if (strcmp(argv[i], PLACEHOLDER) == 0)
          argv[i] = secret;
    }

    real_main = main;

    return real___libc_start_main(mymain, argc, argv, init, fini, rtld_fini, stack_end);
}
```

**On the main c application:**

```
static const char * shc_x[] = {
"/*",
" * Copyright 2019 - Intika <intika@librefox.org>",
" * Replace ******** with secret read from fd 21",
" * Also change arguments location of sub commands (sh script commands)",
" * gcc -Wall -fpic -shared -o shc_secret.so shc_secret.c -ldl",
" */",
"",
"#define _GNU_SOURCE /* needed to get RTLD_NEXT defined in dlfcn.h */",
"#define PLACEHOLDER \"********\"",
"#include <dlfcn.h>",
"#include <stdlib.h>",
"#include <string.h>",
"#include <unistd.h>",
"#include <stdio.h>",
"#include <signal.h>",
"",
"static char secret[128000]; //max size",
"typedef int (*pfi)(int, char **, char **);",
"static pfi real_main;",
"",
"// copy argv to new location",
"char **copyargs(int argc, char** argv){",
"    char **newargv = malloc((argc+1)*sizeof(*argv));",
"    char *from,*to;",
"    int i,len;",
"",
"    for(i = 0; i<argc; i++){",
"        from = argv[i];",
"        len = strlen(from)+1;",
"        to = malloc(len);",
"        memcpy(to,from,len);",
"        // zap old argv space",
"        memset(from,'\\0',len);",
"        newargv[i] = to;",
"        argv[i] = 0;",
"    }",
"    newargv[argc] = 0;",
"    return newargv;",
"}",
"",
"static int mymain(int argc, char** argv, char** env) {",
"    //fprintf(stderr, \"Inject main argc = %d\\n\", argc);",
"    return real_main(argc, copyargs(argc,argv), env);",
"}",
"",
"int __libc_start_main(int (*main) (int, char**, char**),",
"                      int argc,",
"                      char **argv,",
"                      void (*init) (void),",
"                      void (*fini)(void),",
"                      void (*rtld_fini)(void),",
"                      void (*stack_end)){",
"    static int (*real___libc_start_main)() = NULL;",
"    int n;",
"",
"    if (!real___libc_start_main) {",
"        real___libc_start_main = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, \"__libc_start_main\");",
"        if (!real___libc_start_main) abort();",
"    }",
"",
"    n = read(21, secret, sizeof(secret));",
"    if (n > 0) {",
"      int i;",
"",
"    if (secret[n - 1] == '\\n') secret[--n] = '\\0';",
"    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)",
"        if (strcmp(argv[i], PLACEHOLDER) == 0)",
"          argv[i] = secret;",
"    }",
"",
"    real_main = main;",
"",
"    return real___libc_start_main(mymain, argc, argv, init, fini, rtld_fini, stack_end);",
"}",
"",
0};

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#define PR_SET_PTRACER 0x59616d61
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/filter.h>
#include <linux/seccomp.h>
#include <linux/audit.h>

void shc_x_file() {
    FILE *fp;
    int line = 0;

    if ((fp = fopen("/tmp/shc_x.c", "w")) == NULL ) {exit(1); exit(1);}
    for (line = 0; shc_x[line]; line++) fprintf(fp, "%s\n", shc_x[line]);
    fflush(fp);fclose(fp);
}

int make() {
    char * cc, * cflags, * ldflags;
    char cmd[4096];

    cc = getenv("CC");
    if (!cc) cc = "cc";

    sprintf(cmd, "%s %s -o %s %s", cc, "-Wall -fpic -shared", "/tmp/shc_x.so", "/tmp/shc_x.c -ldl");
    if (system(cmd)) {remove("/tmp/shc_x.c"); return -1;}
    remove("/tmp/shc_x.c"); return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

    shc_x_file();
    if (make()) {exit(1);}

    setenv("LD_PRELOAD","/tmp/shc_x.so",1);

    // rest of the code execl etc...
}
```

**Note:** arguments can always be recovered by many ways, this code just makes it a little bit more complicated to reverse.